# How To Get TreeView Model from view to controller on .net core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have a .net core 3.1 MVC project where i am displaying a custom made treeview along with 2 textbox.
Here is the Model i used:

```
public class DeviceGroupAvailabilityModel
{
    public string ChapterTitle { get; set; }
    public string ChapterDetail { get; set; }
    public List<TreeViewModel> TreeViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class TreeViewModel
{
    public string ParentNode { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
    public List<TreeViewModel> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the function that i use to display the tree full on the cshtml file.
[image: dynamicTreeView]

Here is part of the cshtml file:
[image: CshtmlFile]

here is my controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<TreeViewModel> TreeModel = BuildModels(await prtgClient.GetExtendedGroupsAsync(_pRTGApiClient),1);
        DeviceGroupAvailabilityModel deviceGroupAvailabilityModel = new DeviceGroupAvailabilityModel
        {
            ChapterTitle = "Device And Group Availability",
            ChapterDetail = "",
            TreeViewModels = TreeModel
        };
        return View("Index",deviceGroupAvailabilityModel);
    }
    public IActionResult Cancel()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public  async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromForm]DeviceGroupAvailabilityModel deviceGroupAvailabilityModel)
    {
        int reportID = await _dbConnection.GetReportId(deviceGroupAvailabilityModel.ChapterTitle);
        deviceGroupAvailabilityModel.TreeViewModels.Select(async group => await AddGroupToReport(group.ParentNode, reportID));
        return View("Index");
    }
    private async Task AddGroupToReport(string groupName,int reportID)
    {
        int groupId = await _dbConnection.GetGroupId(groupName);
        await _dbConnection.AddGroupToReport(groupId, reportID);
    }
    private List<TreeViewModel>BuildModels(List<ExtendedGroup>extendedGroups,int rootID)
    {
        List<TreeViewModel> TreeModel = new List<TreeViewModel>();
        extendedGroups.ForEach(group =>
        {
            if (group.parentId == rootID)
            {
                TreeModel.Add(new TreeViewModel
                {
                    ParentNode = group.name,
                    ChildNodes = BuildModels(extendedGroups, group.objid)
                });
            }
        });
        return TreeModel;
    }
```

Model Binding from controller to view works great but from view to controller in only get the Two textbox not the list of treeview model.
Is there a way to solve this?
kind regards,

Edit: Full CSHTML Code withoud Title:

```
@model DeviceGroupAvailabilityModel

@functions{      
    void DisplayTree(List<TreeViewModel>models)
    {
         <ul>
           @foreach (TreeViewModel treeViewModel in models)
           {
             <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="@treeViewModel.ParentNode" name="@treeViewModel.ParentNode" checked="@treeViewModel.isChecked" />
                 @treeViewModel.ParentNode
                 @if (treeViewModel.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                 {
                     DisplayTree(treeViewModel.ChildNodes);
                 }
             </li>
           }
        </ul>
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "DeviceGroupAvailability",FormMethod.Post)) {
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="card shadow" style="border-left-color:#0087e9;border-left-width:medium">
                <h6 class="card-header text-center bg-warning">SELECT GROUP TO REPORT</h6>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="tree well">
                        @{

                            DisplayTree(Model.TreeViewModels);
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card shadow ml-3 mb-3" style="border-left-color:#0087e9;border-left-width:medium">
                    <h6 class="card-header text-center bg-warning">CHAPTER TITLE</h6>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ChapterTitle)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card shadow ml-3 mb-3" style="border-left-color:#0087e9;border-left-width:medium">
                    <h6 class="card-header text-center bg-warning">CHAPTER Description</h6>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ChapterDetail)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" class="btn ml-5 bg-primary text-white"  value="Save" />
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-primary ml-5 text-white" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Cancel", "DeviceGroupAvailability")'">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
}


@section Scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(":checkbox").change(function () {
            //begin Cheking all child elements
            var ulsiblings = $(this).siblings("ul");
            var lichilt = ulsiblings.find("li");
            var checkchild = lichilt.find(":checkbox");
            checkchild.prop("checked", this.checked);
            //begin checking Parent element
            //if child is checked
            var checkLiParent = $(this).parent();
            var checkliSiblings = checkLiParent.siblings("li");
            var lisibCheck = checkliSiblings.find(":checkbox");
            var isAllChecked;
            lisibCheck.each(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    isAllChecked = true;
                }
                else {
                    isAllChecked = false;
                }
            })
            if (isAllChecked) {
                var checkParent = checkLiParent.parent();
                var parentSib = checkParent.siblings(":checkbox");
                parentSib.prop("checked", this.checked);
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hi, pls share the code instead of pictures.

Comment: @Rena Sorry for that. it is added now

Comment: Hi, Model Binding binds the property by name attribute. You need to match the name like: The first node level name `TreeViewModels[index].isChecked `, the second node level name `TreeViewModels[index].ChildNodes[index].isChecked `, the third node level name `TreeViewModels[index].ChildNodes[index]..ChildNodes[index].isChecked ` and so on.